# Perl : First number to the base of 2nd number(Base : 2 to 9)

Tags: perl

I am trying this code, but it is giving some answer in the form of Nan.
The `$decimal = ($decimal / $val2);` is incorrect I suppose, not able to figure out what fault is there in this code. 
Is there any other way to calculate this?
Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
sub Base {
    my $val1; 
    my $val2;
    $val1=$_[0];
    $val2=$_[1];
    my $ans;my $i;
    my $decimal;
    my $remainder;
    $decimal=$val1;
    $ans=0;
    $i=1;
    while($decimal > 0)
    {
        $remainder = $decimal % $val2;
        $ans = $ans + ($remainder * $i);
        $i = $i * 10;
        $decimal = ($decimal / $val2);
    }
    print $ans;
}
# Function call
print "enter 1st no.\n ";
my $n1 = <STDIN>;
print "enter 2nd no.\n ";
my $n2 = <STDIN>;
Base($n1,$n2);
```

Comment: It's better if you provide values for $n1 and $n2 and the exact error.

Comment: Thanks @jjmerelo , there's one more catch if i remove "my" declaration its showing error, can you explain a reason for that? actually i am new to the perl, and mixing the concepts of different languages

Comment: `my` declares (creates) a variable.

Comment: Okay i got the concept. Thanks @ikegami

Comment: Actually, `my` declares the *scope* of a variable in Perl. You don't actually need to declare a variable in Perl, you can use it straight away. It's convenient to declare the scope, through. Check this [small tutorial](https://perlmaven.com/scope-of-variables-in-perl) to clarify that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$decimal = $decimal / $val2;
```

should be

```
$decimal = int( $decimal / $val2 );
```

or

```
$decimal = ( $decimal - $remainder ) / $val2;
```

Comment: I got it, it was taking it as a string may be, thanks for your answer.

Comment: What are you talking about? You needed to perform an integer division, but you didn't.